# ColdFusion looping over query with cfqueryparam

Tags: coldfusion, cfloop, cfqueryparam

I am trying to loop over query with a nested query. The code that I have so far:

```
<cfloop query="hashTableLatest">
    <cfquery name="getDifferentImages" dbtype="query">
        SELECT image, imageHash
        FROM hashTable
        WHERE imageHash = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#hashTableLatest.imageHash#" />
    </cfquery>
</cfloop>
```

The problem that I have is that it doesn't loop dynamically through the cfqueryparam. It just gets the first value from the hashTableLatest. Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong? How can I loop through a query and dynamically change the cfqueryparam?

**EDITED**
To get all the information I need in a single query:

```
select a.imageHash
from tblHashLatest a
WHERE a.imageHash in (SELECT c.imageHash
                  FROM tblHash c
              WHERE a.imageHash <> c.imageHash)
```

I think that the above SQL should get me all the information I need. The result I am looking for is to get all imageHashes  that are not same

Comment: Your code is correct and it should be doing what you want. What is making you think that it isn't? Have you used CFDUMP on the inner query to check a) what it contains; b) the SQL & params being used?

Comment: Why are you looping over a query and executing another query in that loop? Look into JOINs and you will be able to do this all in one query,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of options.  One is to not use a loop and just do this:

```
WHERE imageHash in ( 
<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" 
value="#ValueList(hashTableLatest.imageHash)#" list="yes">
)
</cfquery
```

If possible, you should look for ways to get all the information you need from a single query.

Comment: Agreed. Performing additional CFQUERY calls within a loop of a first CFQUERY result is almost always a suboptimal approach to a requirement.

Comment: Using a `JOIN` would be preferable and it should be able to be done in a single query.